# Train Random Forest regressor Model with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I am working on a sentiment analysis project using data extracted in a json format extracted from stocktwits. Every tweet is assigned to a sentiment score which is a float number between 0  and 1. I want to train Random Forest using the pyspark Mllib.

Below is my code:

- I start by reading data from the JSON file into pandas dataframe
- Then convert them to a SparkDF
- After that I have processed this data by removing additional features (punctuation and numbers and stopwords)
- Then I tokenize it and pass it to countvectorizer
- All of this is passed to a Pipeline to get final SparkDF.

I converted the SparkDF to an RDD and then i tried to apply RandomForest model

```
import nltk
import time
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV

import csv
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import regexp_tokenize, wordpunct_tokenize,blankline_tokenize
from nltk import PorterStemmer, LancasterStemmer, SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.util import ngrams
import re
import string
from collections import Counter
import json
import re as regex
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import model_selection, preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import numpy as np
import findspark
findspark.init()
#findspark.init("C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
import pyspark.sql.types as typ
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("local") \
   .appName("Spark ML") \
   .getOrCreate()
#read json file into Spark DataFrame
#create spark dataframe from Pandas DF
df=pd.read_json("Microblog_Trialdata.json")
def list_sp(row):
idx=row["spans"]
#ch="".join(x for x in idx if x)
ch=' '.join(idx)
row["spans"]=ch
return row
df = df.apply(list_sp, axis=1)
train_data=sparkSession.createDataFrame(df)
df.head()
#extraire les champ de sentiment score et tweets
import pyspark.mllib.regression
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
train_data.show()
spans=train_data.select("sentiment score","spans")
#renommer le champ sentiment score en "label"
spans=spans.toDF("label","spans")
#remove some additional features(numbers and unctuatuion)
import pyspark.ml.feature as ft
tokenizer = ft.RegexTokenizer(
inputCol='spans',
outputCol='tokens',
pattern='\s+|[$,.\"]')
#tokenize the text
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
countTokens = udf(lambda words: len(words), IntegerType())
tok = tokenizer \
    .transform(new) \
#now remove stopwords from the review(list of words)    
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover

remover=StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokens", outputCol="filtered")
filtered_df=remover.transform(tok)
#now make 2-gram model
from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram

ngram=NGram(n=1, inputCol="filtered", outputCol="n-gram")
gram_df=ngram.transform(filtered_df)
#apply countvectorizer model
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

# fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus.
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="n-gram", outputCol="features", vocabSize=20, minDF=2.0)

model = cv.fit(gram_df)

result = model.transform(gram_df)
#former le pipeline totale
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, remover, ngram,cv])
pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(spans)
final_df = pipelineFit.transform(spans)
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest
model = RandomForest.trainRegressor(train_df,{}, numTrees =10,maxDepth =None,maxBins =32, seed=42)
```

Comment: Add the config/code you have already developed

Comment: As Nitin already wrote, please provide more details when writing a question on SO. For example config files or any other document that might better describe your domain. Usually some previous Google research about the topic is encouraged instead of asking directly for the solution.

Comment: ok sorry i have edited it

Comment: You've shown us your code but you don't really explain what your problem is.  What is happening that you don't want to happen (or isn't happening that you _do_ want to happen)?  You might find the guidance in [tour] and [ask] and [mcve] helpful.

Comment: Ok so in fact when i tried to apply Random Forest model an error occured asking me to use RDD not Spark dataframe ,the problem that i don't know how to convert my final Dataframe to the Right RDD

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is converting the dataframe to RDD, than you just have to use .rdd like this

```
    newRDD = yourdataframe.rdd
```

Comment: thanks mouna for your suggest i have already solve the problem by refering to pyspak.ml package wich works dierctly with dataframaes